# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que cierto contenido solo le aparezca al usuario indicado?

Tags: javascript, validación, contraseña

Me refiero a que por ejemplo en un blog solo al poner el usuario y la contraseña correctas puedas acceder a la cuenta. Hasta ahora en mis clases de html solo me he dedicado a "fingir" que iba a la cuenta con el usuario y eso, aunque en realidad el enlace estaba en el botón de "enviar" y era el mismo siempre.

¿Hay alguna forma para que se valide y prive el acceso al resto de usuarios? ¿Se haría con alguna función de javascript? No sé nada del tema, así que si alguien pudiera decirme alguna función que haga eso o me pudiera explicar alguna forma me ayudaría mucho.

Comment: Hola Cecilia. Te felicito por pensar un paso adelante. Es una habilidad que marca la diferencia entre un buen programador y un programador de élite. La respuesta corta al título de tu pregunta es: *Con Autenticación y Autorización*. A como está escrita tu pregunta, la respuesta es inmensa y no tiene sentido responderla. Por qué? Porque es un problema que ya tiene soluciones estándar y ampliamente aceptadas. Entonces, te invito a investigar acerca de cómo añadir autenticación a tu aplicación. Qué framework y lenguajes utilizas? .Net? NetCore? Java? React? Vue? Angular? Ruby?

Comment: La cosa es que sé solo lo más básico de html y css, porque no nos enseñaron nada más allá de eso. No sé qué es un framework ni nada. Ahora que me has dicho esto ya sé más o menos por dónde buscar. Buscaré sobre "autenticación" y "autorización" a ver si encuentro cómo hacerlo y aprendo algo más. ¡Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!